# Use Aggregate with $near query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to run a query on a mongoDB and use `$near`in the query. This query below works, but I need to aggrate based on LAT and LNG. I am trying to aggregate or get a count based on those that are within a certain distance to pickup_location.

I am using the below in a **shell**, NOT code.

HERE IS A RECORD:

```
                            {
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5445ab058767000062"
},
"comment": null,
"dropoff_address": "XHgwMmB7fk1lRn59YFx4MDM=U2FsdGVkX19s3u4NEtImfofJzxnGreGpsna8qA4uVrq7exRDVy+zPn5UwDOj\nzpIs",
"dropoff_location": [
    -97.816991,
    30.189151
],
"pickup_address": "XHgwMmB7fk1lRn59YFx4MDM=U2FsdGVkX1/23mD3Vv3Nyf4/t+AEickIgOlkaxVp5y/e/5Ia2d3Z0OXtnejw\nrOK+ZPvxQontA9SS30t+MbUIrCMhndxpYcKNFm4xfOzRVxM=",
"pickup_location": [
    -97.82075191025548,
    30.20993147664687
],
"scheduled_request": false,
"status": "blah",
"timestamp_requested": {
    "$date": "2014-10-21T00:38:28.990Z"
},
"total_owed_in_cents": 0,
"total_received_from_in_cents": 0,
"user_id": "5445a9000057"
```

}

THIS WORKS:

```
db.thing_requests.aggregate(
       [
         {$match: {total_received_in_cents: {$gt:1800}, requested_type: 'Blah' }},
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: null,
               average: { $avg: "$total_received_in_cents" }
             }
         }
       ]
    )
```

NEED THIS ADDED TO WHAT WORKS ABOVE:

```
{
     the_location: {
       $near: {
         $geometry: {
            type: "Point" ,
            coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
         },
         $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
         $minDistance: <distance in meters>
       }
     }
  }
```

## UPDATE:

The top query works. What I need is to say all the items that are aggregated I also need to be sure they are NEAR a certain LAT & LNG.

UPDATE 2:

Ran this query

```
      db.thing_requests.aggregate([
           {
             $geoNear: {
                near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -97.888,37.3222 ] },
                distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                maxDistance: 2,
                minDistance :1,
                query: {total_received_in_cents: {$gt:1800}, requested_type: 'Blah' },
                includeLocs: "dist.location",
                num: 5,
                spherical: true
             }
           },
         {
           $group:
                 {
                   _id: "$user_id",
                   average: { $avg: "$total_received_from_requester_in_cents" }
                 }

         }
        ])
```

RECEIVED THIS ERROR:

```
assert: command failed: {
      "errmsg" : "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }",
      "code" : 16604,
      "ok" : 0
    } : aggregate failed
    Error: command failed: {
      "errmsg" : "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }",
      "code" : 16604,
      "ok" : 0
    } : aggregate failed
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
        at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
        at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
        at (shell):1:23
    2017-08-28T21:21:40.153-0500 E QUERY    Error: command failed: {
      "errmsg" : "exception: geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"no geo indices for geoNear\" }",
      "code" : 16604,
      "ok" : 0
    } : aggregate failed
        at Error (<anonymous>)
        at doassert (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:11:14)
        at Function.assert.commandWorked (src/mongo/shell/assert.js:254:5)
        at DBCollection.aggregate (src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1278:12)
        at (shell):1:23 at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

Comment: What do you mean by "added"? You cannot use `$near` in any other pipeline stage other than the **first** since it **needs an index**, and then really you likely want [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) instead since that is a special pipeline stage that actually returns the "distance" as a value added to the document, which is usually important when you manipulate results further and possibly change the order returned. You should instead show a small sample of data and the result you expect to achieve.

Comment: I updated to illustrate what I am looking for.

Comment: Sounds like `$geoNear` with the other query added to the `query` option of that pipeline stage. You can also simply include the `$near` with the other conditions in the `$match` since you don't really **need** the distance output if you just want to aggregate an average from the returned documents. Note that there "is a difference" in that `$geoNear` returns `100` documents only by default. You can "tune" that, but if you have an indeterminate number where the distance value does not matter than you should probably just add the `$near`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $geoNear in first stage

```
db.thing_requests.aggregate([
   {
     $geoNear: {
        near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ long,lat ] },
        distanceField: "dist.calculated",
        maxDistance: 2,
        minDistance :1,
        query: {total_received_in_cents: {$gt:1800}, requested_type: 'Blah' },
        includeLocs: "dist.location",
        num: 5,
        spherical: true
     }
   },
 {
   //use $group here
 }
])
```

you can use $near too

```
db.thing_requests.find( {
   the_location: {
 $near: {
   $geometry: {
      type: "Point" ,
      coordinates: [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
   },
   $maxDistance: <distance in meters>,
   $minDistance: <distance in meters>
 }
 },total_received_in_cents: {$gt:1800}, requested_type: 'Blah'
 });
```

but in any case you need to specify a geospatial (2d,2dsphere) index on the "the_location" field
if you are using mongoose there is a simple way to do this 
specify 2d or 2dsphere index like this in your schema

```
    the_location: {
    type: [Number],   // format will be [ <longitude> , <latitude> ]
    index: '2dsphere'       // create the geospatial index
}
```

or use  db command

```
db.collection.createIndex( { <location field> : "2dsphere" } )
```

for more perfer https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

Comment: This failed. Error mentioned above in UPDATE 2

Comment: Oh you also need to create geo indexing on the field for which you want to use $geoNear

Comment: $near cannot be used inside of $match

Comment: No my code and your code do not work. I don't want to index my "pickup_location" field as 2dsphere as I am not sure what that will do to the data or system (break something).  Is there a way to 2dsphere it in my query?

Comment: if you do not have any geospatial index in this collection you can make "pickup_location" a geospatial index without breaking anything but if you want then you can use $geoWithin also. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/